# admob banner ad declaration in class giving errors in android

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

In My android game I'm declared admob banner ad in class instead of layout. I had used the following code in `onSetContentView`:

```
 protected void onSetContentView() {
        final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        final AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app-pub-7554016237953661/7036151237");

        adView.refreshDrawableState();
        adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                             FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                             Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM);


        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
        mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine);

        final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

        frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
        frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);

        this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);

    }
```

And in my manifest file i had used:

```
<android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"            
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Error log returns the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
at com.nguyenxuan.fruitmatching.Menu.onSetContentView(Menu.java:132)
at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:62)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which are the lines 62 & 132?

Comment: Did any of the solutions given work?

Comment: Ya I had found the solution., I used Relative Layout for the gameview and Linear layout for the ad.That solved my problem.., anyway thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're using a build target of 19.  Your code will compile but will crash on devices/emulators running on android < Api Level 19 because,

the [FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html)) constructor is available from API 19. You should cast to the older target API 1 [FrameLayout.LayoutParams  (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams source)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html). Modify your code as follows:

```
 final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
               ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) (new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)));

 final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
               ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) (new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                             FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                             Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not caused by admob as is mentioned in your logcat output.

It says `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` is not a method. Wherever you have: `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` replace it with `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and it should solve your problem.