# Android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>

Tags: java, android, nosuchmethoderror

I am getting "NoSuchMethodError" in this code. I have tried to take help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017680/admob-banner-ad-declaration-in-class-giving-errors-in-android) link, but it couldn't help me.I am providing the code with log output.Hopefully these will help you people to understand the problem in the code. Please help me to get rid of it.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {

    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine, this);
    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =(LayoutParams) ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams())));

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
               (LayoutParams) ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) (new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                     FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)));

    // Creating the banner view.
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);

    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(this.getResources().getString(R.string.google_ad_id));

    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) ( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM
                    | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)));

    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    /*final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);*/

    surfaceViewLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 50);
    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);
    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);

}
```

Here is the Logcat output

```
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atcom.mcc.rattle.Rattle2.onSetContentView(Rattle2.java:526)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atorg.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:85)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atandroid.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atandroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2160)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2223)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atandroid.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atandroid.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
11-08 11:57:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is pointing at the line

```
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
           (LayoutParams) ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) (new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)));
```

Comment: first thing that comes to my mind when see such an exception is library/dependency mismatch. Check library compatibility with others.

Comment: try to remove this : (LayoutParams) before ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana I tried, but it shows me "Add Cast to LayoutParams"

Comment: so try to replace (LayoutParams) with (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)

Comment: Just tried it. It is showing exactly same error and problem as before